# Highchart xAxis label click jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following on each xAxis label click.

```
$.each(chartC.xAxis[0].ticks, function(i, tick) {
    tick.label.on('click', function() {
        var drilldown = chartC.series[0].data[i].drilldown;

    });

});
```

it gives ERROR:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

why is this giving error? kindly any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your chart has a x-axis that uses categories that will add an additional tick with index `-1`, to "box in" the categories (ticks appears on the sides of the categories, not directly above). This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd8nquuy/) illustrates your error.

[image: Example of ticks]

This additional tick could cause this problem, as it has no label. In any case, checking for this `-1` index and the existence of a label should be sufficient.

In code this could for example look like ([fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd8nquuy/2/)):

```
$.each(chartC.xAxis[0].ticks, function(i, tick) {
    if(tick != -1 && tick.label != null) {
        tick.label.on('click', function() {
            var drilldown = chartC.series[0].data[i].drilldown;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnx great tip and help.How did you get to know about this method ? did you inspect elements of highchart and tried out? Because I could n't find any related document about this label and ticks event setting from their API docs. Upvoted.